# MAUI-Animating each element of a BindableLayout

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

So, I have a StackLayout that's binded to a list of items, esentitally functioning like a List/Collection view and it looks similar to this:

```
  <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:DataType="Item">
              <Frame>
              ..........
              </Frame>
          </DataTemplate>
      </BindableLayout>
  </StackLayout>
```

What i want to do is to add an animation when each of the frame renders. The code for my animation works fine but when I bind it to the frame of each item, the animation plays all at once for all the items while I want it to start delayed for each of them, for a staggering effect. Basically something similar to the animation presented in [this dev blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-maui-preview-5/)
.

From what I've seen there is no longer an AttachedHandler to any of the MAUI components, and rather you'd have to use Behaviors which seem a little confusing. I tried following the documentation on Behaviors and added a custom animation to the Loaded event of the items, but the end result is the same, all animations playing at once.

Also, I've had a lot of other issues by using ListViews/CollectionViews so I'd rather stick to the current implementation unless there is no other solution.

Is there any simple way to achieve this sort of effect where each item has a delayed animation?

I've tried iterating through the list and making each animation have a different delay but that didn't work. Trying to delay the animations by using Task.Delay just seems to delay the common animations of the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in your case just replace the `AttachedHandler` event with `VisualElement.Loaded` or `Element.HandlerChanged` instead:

```
<Frame Loaded="Frame_Loaded">


<Frame HandlerChanged="Frame_HandlerChanged">
```

Comment: Seems to work by also adding an incrementing delay to the handler method. Thanks a lot!